Firebase Cloud Messaging in a PWA using topics
I am developing a pwa project with only html, js, and css. This app has login and certain web services that link to another cloud application that I have running. I need to send push notifications to my users through Firebase using their topics.
So far I have tried sending notifications to a specific device using its specific token and they have worked correctly, both in my test environment and in production, with the app open and in the background with the firebase-serviceworker.
But I can't find anywhere how to subscribe to Firebase topics and those notifications, instead of sending them to a token, sending them to a topic.
What I want to know is if it is possible to do it in this way that I am proposing or do I have to completely change the approach and in that case how can I do it?

The JavaScript SDK for Firebase Cloud Messaging does not have a method to subscribe to a topic, but it is possible to accomplish this by calling directly yo the REST API from a trusted environment (such as your development machine, a server that you control, or something like Cloud Functions/Cloud Run).
